# Genitive 'of' phrase

Tags: sentence-meaning, genitive-construction

1.**Roxie is the dog of my girlfriend.**

2.**Roxie is a dog of my girlfriend's.**

I was reading about Genitive 'of' phrases where I found these two sentences in examples. I can't understand why **'s** is added in 'girlfriend' in the second sentence.

Comment: I can't either. Where did you read them? Regardless of what they're trying to teach, anyone would say "Roxie is my girlfriend's dog."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lynne Truss has this to say on the subject:](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Eats_Shoots_Leaves/e2ROR0qqFwwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22a%20friend%20of%20the%20footballer%27s%22&pg=PT48&printsec=frontcover)

> It is time to confess that I have for many years struggled with one of the lesser rules of the apostrophe. I refer to the "double possessive", which is evidently a perfectly respectable grammatical construction, but simply jars with me, and perhaps always will. We see it all the time in newspapers:
>
> > Elton John, a friend of the footballer's, said last night...
> > Elton John, a friend of the couple's, said last night...
> > Elton John, a friend of the Beckhams', said last night...
>
> Well, pass me the oxygen, Elton, and for heaven's sake stop banging on about your glitzy mates for a minute while I think. *A friend of the footballer's*? Why isn't it, "a friend of the footballer"? Doesn't the construction "of the" do away with the need for another possessive? I mean to say, why do those sweet little Beckhams need to possess Elton John twice? Or is that a silly question?
>
> But fight the mounting panic and turn to Rober Burchfield's third edition of *Fowler's Modern English Usage* (1998), and what do I find? The double possessive is calmly explained, and I start to peel away the problem. Do I have any objection to the construction "a friend of mine" or "a friend of yours"? Well, no. I would never say "a friend of me" or "a friend of you". And yes, you *would* say "a cousin of my mother's", "a child of hers". Well, "a friend of the footballer's" is the same thing! The only time you drop the double possessive is when, instead of being involved with an animate being, you are "a lover of the British Museum", because obviously the British Museum does not—and never can—love you back.

*Eats, Shoots and Leaves* is a wonderful book on the use and misuse of punctuation and I recommend you read it if you can.